# Conveying meaning using "such as"

Tags: technical-writing

I am having trouble deciding if the use of "such as" in sentence 1 conveys the meaning correctly, or does the meaning need to be reiterated like in sentence 2. I hope this makes sense.

1. This can be caused by defective hardware, such as a hard drive, and corrupt software, such as a device driver.
2. This can be caused by defective hardware, such as a faulty hard drive, and corrupt software, such as an incorrectly versioned device driver.

Comment: (2) reads better to me - (1) seems to imply that _all_ device drivers are corrupt.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you can clarify the sentence by changing the "and" to an "or" and by repeating more of the structure of the first part in the second part: for example _This can be caused by defective hardware, such as a faulty hard drive, **or it can be caused by** corrupt software, such as an incorrectly versioned device driver._

Comment: I'm probably in the minority, but I don't think adding the synonyms -- "faulty" for "defective" and "incorrectly versioned" for corrupt -- adds anything. In fact, an "incorrectly versioned" device driver is not "corrupt," it's just the wrong version. I think the original sentence is fine to give specific examples of "hardware" and "corrupt software". The question in the user's mind is, what kind of hardware and software are you talking about, and the examples answer that.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I am endeavouring to be more precise with my examples.

Comment: @user8356. An incorrectly versioned file can be considered corrupt in some instances, for example, a incorrectly versioned Windows system file can be classed as corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Sentence number two is more clear. It provides greater detail and description to the reader, but not because of any change using 'such as'--because you use more describing words: 'faulty' and 'incorrectly versioned'. It's best to give description when otherwise one would be implying that all of something from a category (hard drives/device drivers) would be defective.